# Why am I getting this error despite typing in the code the same as the book?

Tags: python-2.7

I am completely new to coding. I am going through a very basic beginner book on python and have not had any problems until now.

The practice code in the book is to make our first dictionary like

```
states = {
   'Alabama':  'AL',
   'Alaska':  'AK',
   'Arizona':  'AZ',
   'Arkansas':  'AR',
   'California':  'CA',
   'Colorado':  'CO',
   'Connecticut':  'CT',
 }
```

And then make another similar dictionary w/ capitals.

Then, we print the states, then the capitals, then the states + the capitals.

The problem is that I print the states,

```
for states, abbrev in states.items():
     print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (states, abbrev)
```

and that gives me what I want, but if I try to print the states again in any fashion

```
for states, abbrev in states.items():
     print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (states, abbrev)
```

I get the following error in my powershell, **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'**.

I am typing in the code exactly how it is in the book and still getting this error. I cannot figure it out by searching online.

So, why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: since you are new to coding, here is a tip ... line up all the abbreviations in a neat column ... it will make your code much less cluttered looking ... it will also make it much easier to spot missing commas

Answer (score 1):

```
for states, abbrev in states.items():
     print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (states, abbrev)
```

You are using the same name (`states`) for both the dictionary and the key (`for states ... states.items()`).

After this loop runs, `states` is still bounded to the last key the loop visited, and in fact, you are losing access to the `states` dictionary.

Use a different name for the dictionary and the iteration variable, for example:

```
for state, abbrev in states.items():
     print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)
```

which also makes more sense, because in each iteration the key is an individual state.